# BlackBerry Simulator works very slowly

Tags: java, blackberry

When I ever debug or run my Blackberry app the blackberry emulator 9900 starts very slowly and every time i have to restart the emulator to debug the app again and again.
Is there any other way to run the blackberry application which is faster than blackberry emulator 9900?

Comment: Try taking a look [at this old BlackBerry blog](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2009/08/how-to-set-up-a-lightning-fast-blackberry-smartphone-simulator/).

Comment: clean simulator and try again

Comment: Recent eclipse BB plugin version allow to run or debug without closing the simulator.